# __name__ variable equals "wsgi" instead of "__main__"

Tags: python, server, wsgi

I have wsgi file, where there is a line:

**wsgi.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But today my server didn't start and when I printed `__name__`,  saw that it equals "wsgi" for no reason. I start my server like "sudo systemctl restart myserver.service"

**myserver.ini**

```
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 3

socket = /var/www/myserver/myserver.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
logto = /var/www/myserver/server.log
enable-threads = true
```

**myserver.service**

```
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myserver
After=network.target

[Service]
User=savvasenok
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myserver
Environment="PATH=/home/savvasenok/MyServerEnv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/savvasenok/MyServerEnv/bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/myserver/myserver.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Your wsgi-Server is running your `app`. So the problem must be somewhere else in your configuration. Look at the log-files.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel i dont see anything similar in my [logs](https://pastebin.com/UxWmYHUx)

Comment: The logs say, the server is running. So your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You don’t execute ˋwsgi.pyˋ. Why do you expect it to be ˋ__main__ˋ?

Comment: It always was working the right way till today, so cant answer you

Answer (score 1):

As it explains in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/):

> If the source file is executed as the main program, the interpreter sets the `__name__` variable to have a value `“__main__”`. If this file is being imported from another module, **name** will be set to the module’s name.

So the reason is that you are running a python module (or file) which imports `wsgi`. In your case I think you imported `wsgi` to the `/home/savvasenok/MyServerEnv/bin/uwsgi` module which you sat as `ExecStart` and is being executed.

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/8342406) for more information.